# Is there a project to generate a widget like uservoice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build a widget like uservoice that it lays on the left side or right side of the page. And when user click the widget, a dialog will popup and user can do anything we provide.

Is there an exist open source  project to implement this widget?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the feedback button that hovers on the edge of the page?

I don't know of an open source project, but its not very hard to implement this your self.  A quick google search found several tutorials.  Here's a good one:

http://mediaformations.com/creating-a-simple-feedback-button/

Comment: No, what I want to implement is to give user a simple javascript code and user can see a widget button, click the button, there is a popup window displayed

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you are looking for, so I can better understand what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A widget is nothing, but some HTML code or JavaScript code that loads some HTML code.
A simple solution will be iFrames that gets content from another URL.